# Create a triangle with Dynamic direction WITH SCSS

Tags: html, variables, sass, scss-mixins

Please any help i want to create a dynamic direction of triangle with scss im using mixin but it does not work for me

**file HTML**

`<div class="arrow-div">Arrow</div>`

**file of scss**

```
.arrow-div{
  font-size: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  position: relative;
  @include arrow(red,-40px,null,null,50%,top,translateX(-50%));
}

@mixin arrow($color,$top,$right,$bottom,$left,$dir,$translate){
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
  border: 20px solid transparent;
  position:$dir;
  top:$top;
  right:$right;
  bottom:$bottom;
  left:$left;
  transform: $translate;
  border-#{$dir}-color: $color;
}
```

this is my code bellow
https://codepen.io/aminanba/pen/XWegBbx

Comment: To be honest I would just use an SVG and rotate it accordingly to the direction.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the solution to create dynamic direction of an arrow with scss , mixin and if control flow ;

```css
@mixin arrow($direction:up ,$color) {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border: 20px solid transparent;

  @if $direction == "up" {
    top: -40px;
    left: 50%;
    border-bottom-color: $color;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  } @else if $direction == "right" {
    right: -20px;
    top: 50%;
    border-left-color: $color;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  } @else if $direction == "down" {
    bottom: -40px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    border-top-color: $color;
  } @else if $direction == "left" {
    left: -20px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    border-right-color: $color;
  }
}

/// test
.element {
  position:relative;
  &:before {
    @include arrow("up", red);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="element"></div>
```